# Firefox undo close windows when multiple tabs open

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

When closing with firefox while having multiple tabs that confirm dialog comes up. Theres a box that ask if you would always like to close when more then 1 tab is open. I accidentally checked that off. How do i undo that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

Tools >
Options >
Tabs >
Warn me when closing multiple tabs.

Answer (score 2):

You can re enable is using `about:config`

- Open a new tab with blank page and type `about:config`
- Accept any security warnings and type `browser.tabs.warnOnClose` and make sure that its true.
- If false, double click and make it true.

Thats it.

Comment: I also had to set `browser.showQuitWarning` to true. I think this is a newer setting.